# Sharing a 5v Supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, raspberry-pi, current-limiting

I want to deploy a Pi Zero in a weatherproof box. I need to provide 5v DC for the Pi and an 8 channel Relay Board and two 5v DC pumps.  I have a 5VDC 5A 25W  single output power supply that seems ample for my needs. Should I just connect the 4 units to 5V and return Or would it be more prudent to use current limiting to each power feed?

Comment: It's up to you and your design considerations, really. When you put protections, you usually assume these would protect from something. Do you have something to protect from in this case?

Comment: Conduction and radiated noise must be attenuated by design.  It is possible, but not just by wiring them in parallel. You need to decouple or filter and shield them.  1st the noise source must be defined in dI/dt or dV/dt or V/R and then the tolerance from interference.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that maybe if one of the pumps failed and shorted it might damage the Pi. I had not considered an interference noise. The power supply is a caged affair and it will share the enclosure with the Pi and the relay board. the pumps will be elsewhere. some of the relays will be switching micro compressors which may also cause interference. Might be going back to the drawing board. Thanks for the comments

Comment: after reading the comments I had a look round the web. A site called Andys Workshop had a feature on filtering USB power that looks useful for my project. http://andybrown.me.uk/2015/07/24/usb-filtering/  if anyone else wants to check it out

Comment: That article was specifically describing the noise of USB from PC and specifically in ADC application. You did not mention any analog circuitry, so if your project is pure digital the only noise you should be concerned with is switching spikes of all those relays and typical noise of DC motors. High capacity caps for the former, small caps on terminals and ferrite choke on wires for the latter should do the job.

Comment: Much bigger problem you haven't mentioned is heat radiation from PSU contained in weatherproof box. At the minimum the box must be metallic (aluminum). Ideally, however, the PSU switching elements should be mounted with thermal paste on the inside of the box for direct cooling.

Comment: @Maple I agree on the thermal issue, the Op (P.W.) is making too many assumptions and lacks the design skills to make noise-free except by luck.